# how to combine recursive CTE and normal CTE

Tags: postgresql

I want  a first a normal CTE on table and followed by a recursive CTE

how can I combine this two?

I know for multiple pure normal CTE I can do

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
), CTE2 AS(),...
```

so I have tried

```
WITH CTE1 AS(
), RECURSIVE CTE2()
```

but that gives me a syntax error

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just put the `recursive` at the start, even if the recursive one comes later:

```
with recursive cte1 as (
 ...
), cte2 as (
  -- here comes the recursive cte
  ...
)
select *
from ...
```